# How to limit annotated queries to a single column in Django's ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a table map(*id*, key, value) from where I would like to select the keys that have same value. In SQL I could do

```sql
SELECT key FROM map WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM map GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

I tried to translate it into Django's ORM style

```python
from django.db.models import Count

Map.objects.filter(value__in=Map.objects.values('value').annotate(count=Count('value')).filter(count__gt=1)).values('key')
```

But it fails because the subquery in the `__in` filter returns two columns, the selected `value` column and a column for the count:

```sql
SELECT "map"."key" FROM "map" WHERE "map"."value" IN (SELECT U0."value", COUNT(U0."value") AS "count" FROM "map" U0 GROUP BY U0."value" HAVING COUNT(U0."value") > 1)
```

How can I remove the uneeded `count` column from that subquery?

Comment: Have you tried to do this using `Subquery`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: @markwalker_ Limit the subquery to a single column is what I want, but `.values()` won't limit annotations to a single column except that column being the annotation itself. Also that query in `__in` filter is an implicit subquery, django will inline it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an extra [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Map.objects.filter(
    value__in=Map.objects.values('value').annotate(
        count=Count('value')
    ).filter(count__gt=1).order_by('value').values('value')
).values('key')
```

The [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) part is necessary to remove the `.id` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The order_by query was not needed, the additional `.values()` filter at the end solved it:
```SELECT "map"."key" FROM "map" WHERE "map"."value" IN (SELECT U0."value" FROM "map" U0 GROUP BY U0."value" HAVING COUNT(U0."value") > 1)```. Thank you.